# Query by pagename not Working

Tags: php, wp-query

I try and fail.
What could be the problem with the following code:

```
$pagename = get_post($post_id)->post_name;
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array( 'pagename' => $pagename ));
$result = have_posts() // false
```

The post exists and the variable "$ pagename" is placed approximately.
But the query does not receive a post.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You already have the post when you use `get_post()`. There's no need to query it again.

Comment: I want to get the post template, for example the comments  template will only be on the post page by page name

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. You should update your question with the rest of your code so we can see what you're trying to do.